# Is it possible to export a layer with a related table to kml/kmz and view related data in Google Maps?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, google-maps, kml

I have a polygon shapefile with a related table in ArcGIS 10. When I use the "Layer to KML" tool to export the shapefile and then load it into Google Maps, it doesn't see the related data. I would like the related data to appear in the balloon pop-ups in Google Maps. Is this possible?

Thanks,

Vanessa

Comment: Vanessa-
Did you ever find a solution to this. I have a similar interest and am thinking it would involve creating a customized html popup prior to export. Thanks for sharing your solution if you found one.

Answer (score 1):

Set your HTML pop-up properties for each feature layers you want to export as KML

**HTML popups**

*"Many map layers in ArcGIS are used for accessing rich attributes and other information for each feature. One mechanism is to provide an HTML pop-up display when you click on each feature. This potentially provides a powerful way to share HTML-formatted information, such as web content, about each feature."*

[image]

Your likely to select the radio button 'As table of the visible fields' option

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Mapperz. I had done that, and I can see the data from the attribute table of the polygon layer, no problem. The issue is that I have set up a "relate" to a separate table. In ArcGIS, I can use the Identify tool to display information on a polygon not just from the attribute table, but also any related records from my 2nd table. It's those related records that I would really like to see when I export to KML and view in Google Maps. Any ideas? If it were just a join, I would join and export the layer and table in GIS and then export THAT to KML. A relate seems different...

Comment: If you have a relate - you can export to a new shapefile file and use that it will contain the relate fields too.  Note: ArcGIS is not the best application to manipulate and convert to KML.